# Find the order of $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Find the order of $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$.

For the first part, $\mathbb{R}$ is a group under addition. Therefore, $\left \langle \sqrt{3} \right \rangle=\left \{ \sqrt{3},2\sqrt{3},3\sqrt{3},... \right \}$. Therefore, $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{R}$ has infinite order.

For the second part, $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ is a group under multiplication. Therefore, $\left \langle \sqrt{3} \right \rangle= \left \{ 3^{1/3},3^{2/3},3,3^{4/3},... \right \}$. Therefore, $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$ also has infinite order.

Is this the correct thinking or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt[3]{3}$?  In any case, your conclusion is correct.  Every element of the additive group $\mathbb R$ except $0$ has infinite order, and every element of the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^*$ except $\pm 1$ has infinite order.

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake in the second part!

Comment: Also in the first part.  $\langle \sqrt{3} \rangle$ also includes $\{0, -\sqrt{3}, -2\sqrt{3}, \ldots\}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Opps! Does this also apply for cyclic groups under multiplication?

Comment: Not sure what "this" you mean.  A cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$ (written multiplicatively) is $\{ a^{-3}, a^{-2}, a^{-1}, 1, a, a^2, a^3, \ldots\}$.  It is finite if and only if there is some integer $m$ such that $a^m = 1$.

Comment: There is a slight argument to be made in this problem, although it probably seems like the argument doesn't need to be made. In particular, you must show that $n\sqrt{3}\neq k\sqrt{3}$ for all distinct integers $n$ and $k$. Likewise, $(\sqrt{3})^n\neq(\sqrt{3})^k$ for distinct integers $n$ and $k$. I'm unsure of your education so far, but I'll agree that most courses up to a certain point treat this point as a triviality that doesn't need proven.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but lets make the argument more formal.

The order of an element $g$ from a (multiplicative) group $G$ is a smallest positive integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$ if it exists, otherwise $\infty$.

So in the case of additive $\mathbb{R}$ we are looking at solutions to $n\sqrt{3}=0$. Since $\sqrt{3}>0$ then by induction $n\sqrt{3}>0$ and so this only works for $n=0$. Hence $\sqrt{3}$ has order $\infty$.

In the case of multiplicative $\mathbb{R}^*$ we look at solutions to $\sqrt{3}^n=1$. We can use the fact that $\sqrt{3}>1$ and so (again by induction) $\sqrt{3}^n>1$, which means that the order is $\infty$.